# Displayed 419 Response code while using BlazeMeter script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, blazemeter

I have recorded script using the BlazeMeter & Opened into the `JMeter(4.0)`. While Running the Script in `"View Results Tree"` Result displayed `Response code: 419 with "unknown status".`

Please suggest me the correct solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the token generated during the GET request of login page. 
The token will be present in the Response data section of the login thread in View Result Tree.
You will need to add a Regex expression extractor in the Login thread. Using that you will be able to find the token and then pass it the next page where you are POSTing credentials. You may also have to pass the token to the HTTP Header Manager.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://getstatuscode.com/419 `HTTP 419 response` means that you were authorized to perform certain actions when you recorded the script, but now your authorization token (or any marker that assigns permissions to a user that is used in your case) got expired so that you cannot just rerun your recorded script whenever you want.

You have to consult with the dev team. They should advice on how to amend your recorded script to make it independent from particular run.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be getting this code as [it is not a part of HTTP 1.1 protocol standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

It might be the case your application uses this status code for some form of error, i.e. if you're trying to test a [Laravel-based web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266553/why-laravel-api-return-419-status-code-on-post-and-put-method) and not supplying a valid [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf). If it is the case - you will need to perform **[correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)** - the process of extracting the token from previous response and adding it to the next request using [JMeter PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: l tried using Correlation, but couldnt find the url of the further page. I am getting error right at the login page. So there are only url for Reset password and logo. The thread with POST method while login is not working and giving an Unknown Status error.

Comment: You need to GET login page prior to POSTing credentials, correlation should happen after GET request.